# Different size of nodes in highchart network graph

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, highcharts

[image]In highchart network graph version **"highcharts": "^8.0.4",** unable to define different node size. In nodes array there is no more allow marker radius as shown below this code.

```
nodes: [{
    id: 'Seoul ICN',
    marker: {
      radius: 30,
    },
    color: dirDist50
  }]
```

So, how I define different nodes of different size in highcharts version 8.0.4?

Comment: please add your sample code to question

Comment: @HienNguyen, In this sample code it is not giving an error see at line no: 172 in app.component.ts file.
https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-nsrv1?file=/src/app/app.component.ts

But it gives error at my local code :(
see screenshot in my question I just add

Comment: You should be able to set marker radius easily for each node. API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.networkgraph.nodes.mass The problem is with TypeScript definitions in your local code, not with the Highcharts version. Try to configure your app with this instruction: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/highcharts-typescript-declarations

Comment: @SebastianWędzel, I am looking into it which is you just suggested me, one another question is, can i fix the same length of links? Right now the links of relation nodes are of different length see into this https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9mv0ny3j/

Comment: The length of the link depends on the used algorithm, see: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.networkgraph.layoutAlgorithm.linkLength